# Use PowerMock to mock methods chain with return value

Tags: testing, mocking, testng, easymock, powermock

I want to mock the following code:

```
int num = MySingelton.getInstance().getA().getB().getC();
```

to return a faked number. How do I do it using PowerMock & EasyMock\Mockito ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible . i have created a sample code for you using PowerMockito.

create a singleton class ..

```
public class SingletonClassUtil
{
   private static SingletonClassUtil singletonClassUtil;

   private SingletonClassUtil(){}

   private String name;

   public static SingletonClassUtil getInstance()
   {
      if(singletonClassUtil!=null)
      {
          singletonClassUtil = new SingletonClassUtil();
      }
      return singletonClassUtil;
   }

   public String getA()
   {
      return name;
   }
}
```

now test the class using PowerMock ..

```
public class SingletonTest
{
    public void testSingleton() throws Exception
    {
        PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.constructor(SingletonClassUtil.class));
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(SingletonClassUtil.class);
        SingletonClassUtil singletonClassUtil =  PowerMockito.mock(SingletonClassUtil.class);

        PowerMockito.when(singletonClassUtil.getA()).thenReturn("A");
        System.out.print(singletonClassUtil.getA());
        // add your code here to access inner class methods  
    }
}
```

Vote me if it helps you